# Uploading from HTML5 filesystem api

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, html

I'm making use of the html5 filesystem api, and I'm trying to upload some images to a C# WebApi;

But these are always empty. no mater what I try,
I use the following code in the API

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/quotation/pictures")]
public HttpResponseMessage PostImages() {
    try {
        _logger.Trace("Post pictures ...");
        NameValueCollection parameters = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params;
        string filename = parameters.GetValues("id")[0];
        var files = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
        if (files.Count > 0) {
            // .. other code
        }
    }
}
```

And the following code in JS

```
// img = variable with some img options.
var data = new FormData();
fileService.getFile(img.viewpath.split('/').pop()).then(function (f) {
    // f = FileEntry
    data.append(img.FileNameOnDevice, f);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    }).success(defImg.resolve).error(defImg.reject);
}, function () {
    console.error("not found");
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to access the user's file system with JavaScript? Since you can't (in a browser).

Comment: I'm able to use the filesystem to show the files stored in the filesystem (i write them there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an easy fix,

since `f` was a FileEntry, I had to request the file itself, so changing the code to:

```
// img = variable with some img options.
var data = new FormData();
fileService.getFile(img.viewpath.split('/').pop()).then(function (f) {
    // f = FileEntry
    f.file(function(file){
        data.append(img.FileNameOnDevice, file);
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        }).success(defImg.resolve).error(defImg.reject);
    }, defImg.reject);
}, defImg.reject);
```

solved the issue